# Best practice for verifying a GitLab user?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Given I have a existing project and I want to add an external GitLab user to the project.

The user can enter his/her GitLab username (and additional fields if needed) in a UI.

**What is the best practice to verify that the user is valid and that the user is the real owner of the entered account over the GitLab API?**

*This should also support external login methods (GitHub, ...).*